# Asymmetry in definition of regular measure

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question

> In a Borel measure space $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$, $\mu$ is outer regular at $E$ if
>     \begin{equation}
>     \mu(E) = \inf_{U \textrm{ open}} \{\mu(U): U \supseteq E\}
>   \end{equation}
>     and inner-regular if
>     \begin{equation}
>     \mu(E) = \sup_{U \textrm{ compact}} \{\mu(U): U \subseteq E\}.
>   \end{equation}

What's the motivation for the asymmetry in the definition? I.e. why for outer regularity do we require $U$ to be open and for inner regularity we require $U$ to be compact?

Comment: Do you think it would be more natural with closed instead of compact?